# making a volumetric XYZ array in geometry nodes

Tags: modifiers, node-editor, geometry

How do I make a geometry nodes setup that does the following WITHOUT using the array modifier,

1. volumetric grid, of evenly spaced instances of a collection (containing two objects that need
   to retain their transform data from the collection) in xyz space
2. the instances need to have random position transform introduced over time the value of which
   needs to be animatable to give them the appearance of a wiggle, that's it.

I'm losing my mind over this seemingly simple aspect of a gig, its been days, I'm kind of at a loss over how complicated this has become, it seems like such a simple straight forward thing, is this possible?

[image]

Comment: I get worried by "how to do x without using y" questions.  There's a reason you don't want to use an array modifier.  What reason is that?  Because it's entirely possible I could give you an answer that doesn't use it, but that doesn't address that reason, and then I'd have wasted my time.

Comment: I'm instancing a alembic of a fluid sim, the array makes the instances duplicates and makes this impossible, I've found tutorial that kind of does this by building a width and a height node and then multiplying that but I cant figure out how implement the random movement I need, 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GD5n27m7_Yo&t=519s

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Geometry Nodes has changed quite a bit since that tutorial, with the introduction of Fields, but the logic of creating a 3D array is still much the same.

The array is created by

1. Creating a subdivided line
2. Instancing a grid on each point of the line.

In this example, the count and dimensions of the grid and the line are controlled by the same parameters, so the overall bounding-box and the cells remain cubic.

The Grid-Instances are *Realized*, so the layers do not share point-IDs. This allows random distribution of the collection elements through the volume, not just per-layer.

In this example, - the available controls in the modifier interface are:

- `Count` - The number of cells to a side of the cube
- `Cell Size` - The length of the side of each cell
- `Element Bias` - The proportion of each of the 2 elements in the collection represented in the array
- `Jitter Amount`-The amplitude of translation from cell-center when the element locations are randomized
- `Seed` - The seed of that randomisation.

[image]

This may not exactly meet your specification? You may want more control over the distribution of elements, or send a continuous noise-ripple through the array, rather than a random jitter.. etc. But perhaps this is a start.

[image]

(Blender 3.0b)

[image]

Comment: This is 99% of the way there! Thank you!
problems, I'm still having, my alembic instance now just show up as an empty, is there a way to instance the whole collection is it appears in the collection (a small mesh placed inside the alembic, in the shot its a particle of dust inside a rain cloud) instead of each object in the collection appearing as its as its own object per grid point?

Comment: excuse me *a particle of dust inside a raindrop*

Comment: I'm probably being dim, not very experienced with alembics. Do you mean each instance contains its own animation? You can certainly instance [whole collections] at  each point, rather than [picked children of collections], if that's what you mean.

Comment: that is correct, I'm definitely dim on the mechanics of how any of this works, what input node would I use to do that and where would it plug in?

Comment: I'm using an alembic export of a flip fluids sim with a static model nested inside of it, hope that clears that up

Comment: To get [Whole Collection] per point, that would be unchecking 'Separate Children' in the Collection Info node.. not sure about the animation.  You may have to provide an in-principle, 'toy'  example of what you're referring to, to be completely unambiguous.

Comment: I got it! Thank you so much! I'll post screen shots of the mod I did to your setup when I finish the project.

Comment: @o88 Great! It's nice to see results of suggestions :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131083/discussion-between-o88-and-robin-betts).