# how to obtain only one bar from this

Tags: mesh

i divided the cube into sub pieces by loopcut as seen in the picture. now all I want is to obtain one vertical bar from this and get rid of everything else. i think i can do this by selecting some vertices and deleting them but can you show me a better way? so again, out of these 16 vertical bars that you see that make up this cube, I want to obtain only one of them and get rid of the rest. what is the best way?[image]

Comment: Do you just want to keep one face or the complete block across the cube? - A sketch of exactly what you want to keep would help.

Comment: I don't understand your question. As I stated in my question I want to obtain one vertical bar from here, where currently there are 16 bars.

Comment: Hello could you please show a drawing of how it is supposed to look?

Comment: The cube in the picture is made of 16 vertical bars. I want to get rid of 15 of them and keep just one. No need to attach another photo to my question.

Comment: Select the 15 bars and Ctrl X to dissolve?

Comment: Also, Alt Ctrl RMB to select an edge ring (then Shift LMB to remove from selection)

Comment: LMB Select the face, Ctrl-I invert selection, X delete?

Comment: "The cube in the picture is made of 16 vertical bars. " I seriously doubt it. I guess that what we are looking at is one cube made up from the usual 6 surfaces, 4 of which are divided into 4 lengthy faces each, the other two divided into 16 square subfaces each.

Comment: If you remove what you perceive as "the other bars", you end up with something with two square faces and four non-surfaces without any face (in case of keeping one form the inside) or two square faces, one lengthy face (in case of one on the side but still somewhat in the middle) or two square face and two lengthy faces (in the case of keeping one on a corner).

Comment: Several people have asked you to provide how the result should look like, because they want to know what you really expect, which part you want to keep and whether you are aware of the different kinds of non-faces - and (if I guessed wrong) whether you are really right in saying that this cube consists of 16 bars with 6 actually existing faces each. I doubt it, because then I suspect that you would not have any problem.

Comment: If you still cannot, or decide for other reasons not to, provide a desired result sketch, please at least answer this question: How many faces do exist in what you show? If you are right in stating that this cube consists of 16 bars, then the number of faces should be 64. I expect however, that you only have 48. Note that the number of vertices is the same in both cases, they are all visible from the outside of the cube. (Everybody feel free to find and point out errors in my math/counting. I am only bean counting to help OP become aware of relevant geometry difference.)

Comment: moonboots your first method works, but I couldnt do it with your second method. Robin, CTRL I is really good trick, I didnt know this but good to learn. This is why I asked such a simple question while beginner level, to learn correct practices. Yunmosh, as you can see, when you want to understand something, you just understand it. No need to make things complicated. The question is simple and so were the answers from 2 people who solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what's throwing people is that the common way to model is not subtractive like  this - to obtain the column you are looking for, the simplest way would be to add a a plane, subdivide it 3 times, select one of the faces, extrude it "up" by 2, select and delete all the rest of the faces and make a face to fill the "hole" in the bottom.

[image: Sub1]

[image: Ext]

[image: Del]

[image: Fac]

Although, even easier than this, however (given your desired dimensions), would be to take a default cube, enter edit mode and scale by 0.25 along the X and Y axis, but not the Z (S + Shift+Z + .25)

Comment: or elect the cube, hit N, and adjust dimensions. so i learned myself. yours is good way too thanks

Comment: Nice! - There are at least 6 ways I can think of offhand to accomplish the same thing, glad you found one on your own. Keep practicing, you'll see how trivial this kind stuff becomes pretty soon.

Comment: This post might be another approach you could take - essentially creating the columns as an array, then look at how to select a single instance desired: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/242103/making-a-volumetric-xyz-array-in-geometry-nodes